# Why is it a good idea in measure theory to define $0\times\infty=0$?

Tags: measure-theory

Reading about measure theory has led me to consider extended real numbers. I have read that in this context $0\times\infty$ is *defined* as $0$. The wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line supports this claim.

Of course, I am familiar with the usual thing said in calculus courses that $0\times\infty$ is not a well defined thing (or better said, products of functions with zero and infinity as limits can have as a limit zero, infinity or any other real number).

In any case, I am interested in knowing *why* in the context of measure theory it is a good idea to define $0\times\infty=0$. What is the motivation?

Comment: maybe see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976329/measure-theory-convention-that-infty-cdot-0-0?rq=1

Comment: You need that to prove that $\int 0 d\mu = 0$

Comment: To re-iterate your second paragraph for posterity, in calculus, "$0 \times \infty$" usually refers not to the sum$\sum_{k} 0$ or the integral $\int_{\mathbf{R}} 0\, dx$ (both of which do have value $0$), but to the _limit of a product_ (which, as you note, is indeterminate).