# Integral of simple functions and the convention $0 \times \infty = 0$

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, simple-functions

I am studying measure theory on my own and there is something about the convention that $0 \times \infty = 0$ that I can's seem to get my head around. I've read various threads now on this topic and it seems that everyone agrees that it cannot be more than a convention, and thus we can't use it to prove any results (see e.g. [Measure theory convention that $\infty \cdot 0 = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976329/measure-theory-convention-that-infty-cdot-0-0))

However, in most sources this convention is introduced right after the definition of the integral of a simple function.

Def: Simple function

Let $(\Omega,\varphi,\mu)$ be a measure space. Then a function $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a simple function if $f=\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{j} \mathbb{1}_{E_{j}} $ s.t. $c_{j} \in \mathbb{R}$,$E_{j} \in \varphi$,$\sum_{j=1}^{n} E_{j}=\Omega$ and $E_{j} \cap E_{k}=\emptyset$ if $j \neq k$.

Def: Integral of simple function

Let f be a non-negative simple function, then we define its integral as

$I(f)=\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{j} \mu(E_{j})$.

With this definition we can run into problems if $c_{j}=0$ and $\mu(E_{j})=\infty$ for some $j$. Is there a way to show that the value of the integral does not depend on the convention $0 \times \infty = 0$. I know that it is possible to prove that the value of the integral does not depend on the particular representation of a simple function, so my idea is to circumvent the problem by using a different representation of a simple function if we run into the case described above. The problem is that I can't find a way how I could prove that for a general function $f$.

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks very much!

Comment: We **don't** run into problems when $c_j=0$ and $\mu(E_j)=\infty$, since then  $f=\sum_{j\ne i}c_j\Bbb 1_{E_j}$. That's why it makes sense in measure theory to adopt the convention $0\cdot\infty=0$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}0\cdot x=0.$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ah, right. If $c_{i}=0$, then we can obviously just take the sum over all $j \neq i$. That's your point, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want can be achieved. Say $\Omega$ is the real line with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra and let $\mu $ be the Dirac measure on $0$. Then any partition of $\Omega$ will have a member with infinite measure, so if $f$ is the zero function you will never be able to avoid the situation $c_j=0$ and $\mu(E_j)=\infty$ for some $j$.